# Asynchronous method in button click

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a problem with loading data in UI. In particular I have a form in which there's a button that loading a new form (is a "Next" button in a Wizard) and loading data. The problem is that when I click button the button remains pressed withount changing the view. Only when the loading data is completed the other view with data is shown. 
Instead I want the new view is showed  when I click button (becouse in this view there are a progress bar that is in progress while loading data is being executed).

How Can I resolve this problem? I tried with task, thread and backgroundworked but without success.

```
bool Initialize()
{
  InizializationForm();
  LoadingData();
  return true;
}
```

Should LoadingData be asyncronous?

Comment: Please add the minimal code of your button pressed handler.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: @Nkosi I've been looking everywhere for that link. Thanks :)

Comment: @Ortund it is from the Help page under Asking https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: You should show the Form at the beginning and then using multi threading loading the data.

Comment: unfortunately I can't post some code becouse using MVVM the code is confused. I'm interesting a logic solution

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: @lightlike thank you I resolved thank to that post with the use of Task.Delay() !